# Quaternion elements go to infinity when giving non-zero input to discrete time system

Tags: drake

I am trying to run a simulation of a floating base robot in discrete time. However, when I give a non-zero input to the robot, the quaternion elements go to infinity. The issue can be reproduced in this [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Wnc-Srz0wPYhsDkruK3EQ253icxvjJHx?usp=sharing) notebook. I do not have the same issue in continuous time, however running the simulation in continuous time takes much longer (10 minutes rather than a couple of seconds) due to the contact points at the robot foot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your system is unstable (or very close to instability).  The continuous-time solver taking a long time is normally an indication that the error-controlled integrator is taking exceedingly small steps.  I suspect there is a problem in your dynamics description.  Perhaps some inertias that are zero or nearly zero?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I made a humanoid lower body urdf to experiment around with and this indeed turned out to be the issue (although the inertias seem fine). The discrete time simulation now works after I switched to a real humanoid urdf.